# how to make this simple javascript closure work

Tags: javascript, closures

I was explaining javascript closure to a friend like this:

```
function outer() {
    var count = 0;
    return (function(){
        count++;
        console.log(count);
    })();
}
```

I was trying to show him that how does this 'count' variable is stored when the outer function is executed.

So I tried doing this in the javascript console and wanted to show him that when you do this in the console

```
outer(); // prints out 1
outer(); // calling again prints 2
outer(); // prints out 3
```

but actually this happened

```
outer(); // printed 1
outer(); // printed 1 again
outer(); // again 1
```

I don't understand whats going wrong here. Can someone guide me.

Comment: You probably meant to return a function. `var myouter = outer(); myouter(); myouter(); myouter()`

Comment: @elclanrs that works for the first time. however calling it again as `myouter();` throws an error "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: `outer` is not returning a function, it is returning `undefined`. Return a function, but don't execute it and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @elclanrs. This is the working code.

```
function outer() {
  var count = 0;
  return (function(){
    count++;
    console.log(count);
  });
}
```

Now when i call this function and store it in a variable

```
var myouter = outer();
myouter();
// 1
// undefined
myouter();
// 2
// undefined
myouter();
// 3
// undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your `count` is declared inside the function, so it is "private" to the function scope, so every time your function is called, the variable `count` will be created and initialized to `0` then your inner function, aka, closure increments it, that is why it prints `1`, then when your closure returns, your `count` variable is garbage-collected because its scope ends there -- within the matching curly braces, try moving `count` to the outermost outside any function, then you will get what you want, then your `count` will become a global variable which is not good in production code because you dont want to taint your global pool, and create memory leak problem. Closures are basically just inner functions like in Java.

Comment: What I want to do is to make `count` private to inner function and still show him the example in this way only. Do you have a way to do that? I wanted to show him how closures is used to keep variables private to themselves. So your answer doesn't applies in this case.

Comment: You can create private variables by enclosing them in your function like you did, but to achieve what you want -- calling your function 3 times and expect your count to be 3, you cant do that since your `count` is scoped to the function, however you can use `setTimeout()` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You set `count=0` every time you call `outer()`. If you want `count` to be private, meaning outside global scope, then I would use a module pattern like this:

```
var counter = (function(c){
    var count = 0;

    c.outer = function(){
        count++;
        console.log(count);
    };
    return c;
}({} || counter))

counter.outer();
```

or you can simply have `outer()` return a function:

```
function outer() {
    var count = 0;
    return function(){
        count++;
        console.log(count);
    };
}

var myo = outer();
myo();
myo();
myo();
```